# Python scripts not working after switch_to.context('webview') when testing on hybrid Android app?

Tags: python, hybrid-mobile-app, python-appium

My python scripts as below:

wrong at the red arrow:

Comment: It is not stable when app switch at native_app and webview,  is there any way to improve stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has resolved via update chrome driver to latest version(51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit)).